# How to add Keylistener to ListSelect in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin `ListSelect` component on which I would like to remove items if the key `DEL` is used.

All I found was the `ShortcutListener` but if I add the following listener, the `DEL` key does not work in the rest of my application (e.g. deleting text in a `TextField`):

```
listSelect.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("", KeyCode.DELETE, null) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4703134138899283799L;

        @Override
        public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
            // handle delete
        }
    });
```

How should I implement a listener for the `DEL` key?

EDIT: Tried to use a wrapper `Panel` as suggested in comments, but it still doesn't work. Here my current code:

```
listSelect = new ListSelect(null);
listSelect.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
listSelect.setHeight(82, Unit.PIXELS);
listSelect.setMultiSelect(true);
listSelect.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);

listSelect.setDescription("Löschen mit der DEL Taste");
listSelect.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("", KeyCode.DELETE, null) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4703134138899283799L;

    @Override
    public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
        // handle delete
    }
});
Panel wrapperPanel = new Panel(listSelect);
form.addComponent(wrapperPanel);
```

The `form` is a `GridLayout`, the parent of `form` is a `Panel`. This panel is part of a `TabSheet`. I'm using Vaadin Version 7.7.1.

Comment: so does this work (except for the fact, that it ruins the rest of the appliation)?  if that's so, then you can try to add a (borderless) panel around that input which should act as a barrier.

Comment: @cfrick that's a very good idea, but at first look, the workaround with the panel seems to require setting the short-cut listener on the panel instead of the list select, otherwise it still behaves like OP described. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [sources (currently line 110)](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.java#L110), it seems that the action is delegated to the containing window...

> ```
> /**
>  * Keeps track of the Actions added to this component; the actual
>  * handling/notifying is delegated, usually to the containing window.
>  */
> private ConnectorActionManager actionManager;
> ```

... or parent container at least, because based on this question [Select-all shortcut (Ctrl-A) in Vaadin Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712271/select-all-shortcut-ctrl-a-in-vaadin-table) you can work around this issue. If you wrap the list select in a panel and add the short-cut listener to the panel instead, it works as expected:

```
public class MyListSelectComponent extends VerticalLayout {

    public MyListSelectComponent() {
        ListSelect list = new ListSelect("Press DEL to remove items");
        TextField input = new TextField("Focus this input and press DEL to delete some text");
        input.setValue("This is some very long text, or not...");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.addItem(i);
        }

        Panel panel = new Panel(list);
        panel.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.DELETE, null) {
            @Override
            public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
                if (list.getValue() != null) {
                    list.removeItem(list.getValue());
                }
            }
        });

        addComponent(panel);
        addComponent(input);
    }
}
```

**Actual output:**

[image: vaadin delete key shortcut listener]

Comment: Hmm, I created a `wrapperPanel` (see the question edit), but it still does not work. What vaadin version are you using?

Comment: @flavio.donze it's 7.6.8, but as I was saying in the answer, the listener must be added on the panel instead of the list select.